# ES6, ES7, ES8 Как использовать и где взять инфу?

Tags: ecmascript-6, es7

Хочу научиться использовать последние стандарты (ES7, ES8), смотрел их разные фишки, хотелось бы попробовать, но как эти стандарты можно активировать?
Видел фишки что то вроде "Точечный синтаксис"
Что-то вроде этого:

```
console.log ('Привет Мир!');
```

можно заменить на

```
c.l.'Привет Мир!'..
```

Comment: Точечный синтаксис вы видели в каком-то другом языке :-)

Comment: Я уже узнал, что это...это был прикол..)
но было бы интересно)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установите nodej и используйте es7-8. Это тот же js, только для сервера. А потом смотрите поддержку нужной "фишки" в браузерах и используете, если поддержка вас удовлетворяет.